# Messages not showing on frontend Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento, magento2

I have multistore view magento 2 shop. Problem appears when messages from mage-messages cookie are about to be displayed. Basically sometimes messages stays in cookie and sometimes just disappear from cookie but never shows on frontend.
I have configured cookie domain and path in magento admin but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.
I have despirately looking for solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

> ***Method-1 Using Module***

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages':'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/view/messages'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

> ***Method-2 Using Theme***

**app/design/frontend/your-vendor-name/your-theme-name/Magento_Theme/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

**Must be run Magento 2 commands after adding the above files**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears that mage-messages that actually contains message to display is now being removed. But the session mage-messages is still available. Can I remove session mage-messaages cookie because that should fix my problem?

Comment: @MilosStambolija Yes and solutions are already posted here.

Comment: I have tried that solution but session mage-messages cookie still sometimes shows and it prevents other one that actually contains message to display.

Comment: @MilosStambolija Please check messages.js file is updated or not. For my case it's working.

Comment: How does providing undocumented custom code explain why standard Magento messaging interface is not working?

Comment: @AdamLavery Please check this github issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36673 and https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7561